# Calculating a Logarithmic Equation in Excel

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, logarithm

How do I use excel formulas to calculate a log equation I can use to project figures?

Here are the following data points:

**Datapoints for LN**

[image: Datapoints for LN]

I have been using `=LINEST(Y,X,1,1)` for C and `1,2` for B with an array but the equation I get doesn't even come close to getting any of figures in my data points when I make X=1 or X=2

When I used
`=INDEX(LINEST(E49:N49,(E47:N47)^Transpose({1,2,3,4...})),1,1)`

I get ~4mil for C and switch to 1,2) I get ~11M for B

So Y= 4m*LN(X)+11M

When I plug in 1,2,3 etc as X I don't even come close to any of the data points.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the log functions? ln(), log() etc?

Comment: Take a look at the `LOGEST` and/or the `GROWTH` functions.